# Kick saves i log channel with embed

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in python and I need some help. I have custom commands to the bot like kick, ban and mute and if you kick or ban someone for example I want it to be saved in a private log channel. Where all kicks, band and mutes are being saved. But I just can't get it to work. And I also want it to be an embed.

This is my code atm

```py
@bot.command(name='kick', pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(context, member: discord.Member):
    await member.kick()
    log = discord.Embed(name='User ' + member.display_name + ' has been kicked')
    save_log = discord.Embed(member.deplay_name, 'has been kicked')
    await context.message.channel.send(embed=log)
    log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(embed=save_log)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> member.**deplay**_name

First of all, you spelled `display` wrong

Second, take a look at your `save_log` variable. You're creating an `Embed` and passed 2 strings to the constructor. You can't do that. Take a look at your `log` Embed on the previous line & compare what you did there.

Third, I can't find anything about a `name` kwarg for an `Embed`, you probably mean `title`?

```
@bot.command(name='kick')
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(context, member: discord.Member):
    await member.kick()
    log = discord.Embed(title='User ' + member.display_name + ' has been kicked')
    save_log = discord.Embed(title=member.display_name + ' has been kicked')
    await context.send(embed=log)
    log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(embed=save_log)
```

PS You can just use `ctx.send` instead of `ctx.message.channel.send`, and `pass_context` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks you both for the help, I saw what mistakes I made now. Like those small mistakes as Embed doesn't have a ``name`` kwarg and those other things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong in your code:

1. Since v1.0.0(rewrite) you don't have to pass `pass_context` in the decorator

```py
@bot.command()
```

2. Embeds don't take `value` or `name` kwarg change it to `title` or `description`

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title='User kicked', description=f'{member.display_name} has been kicked')
```

3. You don't have to use `context.message.channel.send`, you can simply:

```py
await context.send('something')
```

4. There's a typo in `member.deplay_name`

Your code would look like this:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.kick()
    log = discord.Embed(description=f'User {member.display_name} has been kicked') 
    save_log = discord.Embed(description=f'{member.display_name} has been kicked')
    # you can use 'title' instead of 'description' 
    # and probably you want to use the same embed instead of creating two indentical
    await ctx.send(embed=log)
    log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(embed=save_log)
```

Sources:

- [pass_context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=pass_context#command-changes)
- [embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)
- [context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context)
- [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member)